# How to represent time of day (ie. 19:00) in Java?

Tags: java, jodatime

What's the correct way to represent time of day in Java?

For example: 09:00, 19:30, etc.

Basically this is a time of day not linked to an actual date/day.

Comment: Have you heard about [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: Use `LocalTime` from the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: The question doesn't mention parsing or formatting text at all. It just talks about the best way to represent a value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've already tagged this with jodatime.

The Joda Time type for storing a time of day is [`org.joda.time.LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/LocalTime.html). See the Joda Time [API documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: @jarnbjo As the API docs say, `LocalTime` represents a time without a timezone, so it doesn't have anything to do with DST changes. It's just a time of day, not for any specific day. Joda Time has lots of different date and time classes for different purposes.

Comment: I agree that Joda has lots of classes and they are mostly equally poorly documented. The API docs for LocalTime also says "Calculations on LocalTime are performed using a Chronology. This chronology will be set internally to be in the UTC time zone for all calculations.", which partially contradicts your API doc snippet. So even if LocalTime doesn't directly reference a time zone, it references a chronology and the chronology references UTC. Which role does the chronology play and why is it mentioned that the chronology will be set to UTC if LocalTime is TZ-agnostic?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score -3):

Usually, when it's not required to display it, a *long* is used.

See System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis would be a very bad way to represent time of day

Comment: As I said - when it's NOT meant to be displayed. I thought 'without a date' was meant by no java.util.Date. So, a bit too fast to give me bad scores, weren't you ? :-)

Comment: _For example: 09:00, 19:30, etc._ He wants to show Time in human readable format without a date.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: There's no indication that a string conversion is actually required here. The OP is only asking which representation to use - I assumed that 09:00 and 19:30 were examples of the data to be represented, not a string to be shown. (Of course once you've got the right representation you can *build* a string...)

Comment: Regardless of String conversion or no, representing a time of day with currentTimeMillis is just like using a Date object, just worse. You still need a calendar to convert it to hours and minutes.

Answer (score -4):

Like Eng.Fouad suggests, you should still use a Date object. That way you still get access to all the utility that exists for Date objects. Just ignore the date part of it whenever you present it.

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String timeOfDay = df.format(date); // ex: "18:00"
```

Or to create a specific time

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String timeOfDay = df.format(cal.getTime()); // "18:00"
```

Comment: No, you absolutely should *not* use a `Date` object. It's the wrong representation. A `Date` object represents an instant in time, and that's all. (It's badly named.) Joda Time has a type *specifically* for this case - that's the right approach. The Java API is fundamentally broken by not giving enough types to represent the different kind of values which naturally occur in date/time work. Also note that if you *do* use `SimpleDateFormat`, you need to take more care over the patterns - the pattern you've given would never produce "18:00" as you're using the 12-hour clock.